# SaveMode in DataSource API in Spark 3.0.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datasource

I am trying to migrate a custom spark connector that my colleague wrote to spark 3.0. The API has changed drastically (overall for the better IMH). One thing I have a problem figuring out is `SaveMode` that is used for writing a dataframe. It used to be supplied as one of the input arguments of the abstract method `createWriter` of `WriteSupport` trait. However `WriteSupport` has been changed to `SupportsWrite` and the equivalent method(if you can call it that) is `newWriteBuilder` that gets an argument of type `LogicalWriteInfo`, which doesn't have member of type `SaveMode`.

I have also looked into `WriteBuilder`, `BatchWrite`, `DataWriterFactory`, and `DataWriter[T]` to no avail. Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation about this subject. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SaveMode` is on its way out according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25531) issue. Instead, new traits have been added that can accomplish the same functionalities:

[`SupportsDynamicOverwrite`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/write/SupportsDynamicOverwrite.html)

[`SupportsOverwrite`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/write/SupportsOverwrite.html)

[`SupportsTruncate`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/write/SupportsTruncate.html)

Comment: From my experience, when save() operation started in "overwrite" mode the truncate() method of "Supports Truncate" interface is called